# How to figure out the import rules for a given command?

Tags: ms-access

So I'm looking at some access code, and trying to figure out what exactly it's doing. Semi-stuck at the following line:

```
SpecName = "DocLineDetailImportSpec"
    DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, SpecName, tblname, filenm, True
```

Ok, let's do some googling. Microsoft tells us the following:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-transfertext-method-access

Acimportdelin - ok, the default. Sure.
Specname - this is where I'm stuck
Tablename - yup, obviously going to the table named earlier
Filename - yup, obviously grabbing the file we declared earlier in the code
True - Sure, not too concerned about it.

So I'm on Specname - reading the documentation, it's a type of import rule. Ok, where are import rules kept? Apparently, in saved imports (from my googling). I get there and... there are two rules, neither of them have the name, and neither of them appear to have any sort of visibility. I can't see what they're doing (if they were even correct), or anything. How can I figure out (short of brute-force uploading data and tracing it all) what the speccommand is?

Uploading Excel files btw

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question, essentially, boils down to the following: how can I view the import specifications?

Well, in the following way (screenshots: Access 2016)

Step 1: Try to add a new data source -> Text

[image]

Step 2: Go to advanced

[image]

Step 3: Go to specifications

[image]

You can view and adjust import and export specifications here.

Comment: Excellent guide! And yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for. I have Access Office (Microsoft Office 365 Pro Plus) - and in step 2, I see the exact same thing... except for the advanced button. Is there any other way to see the specs?

Comment: Are you sure you've selected New data source -> Text file, and not Excel?